# Having multiple OPTIONAL MATCH in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm looking to form a query what should match on **at least one** of the OPTIONAL MATCH. In this form it would return a result even when *none* of the OPTIONAL MATCH, which is not what  I desire.

`MATCH (media:Media)-[rr:HAS]-(ad:Ad) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (media)--(word:Word) WHERE word.value IN ['thing']
OPTIONAL MATCH (media) WHERE media.description CONTAINS 'something'
RETURN media, collect(DISTINCT word) as word, collect(DISTINCT ad) as ad`

Answer (score 3):

`UNION` would be a better fit in this case. The only caveat is that you return columns with the same alias from each part of the union.

```
MATCH (media:Media)-[rr:HAS]-(ad:Ad) 
MATCH (media)--(word:Word) WHERE word.value IN ['thing']
RETURN media, collect(DISTINCT word) as things
UNION 
MATCH (media:Media)-[rr:HAS]-(ad:Ad) 
MATCH (media) WHERE media.description CONTAINS 'something'
RETURN media, collect(DISTINCT ad) as things
```

This would produce zero results if neither part matches, and at least one if either matches.